# sml syntax having a hard time looking up documentation

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I am trying to "simulate" a pass by value result function with the following code but there seems to be a syntax error. I've been looking through sml tutorials but I'm having a hard time figuring out why this doesn't work

```
1 val x = ref 0;
2 fun p(y': int ref)=
3 let
4   val y = !y'
5     in
6         let
7             y = 1
8             in
9                 let x := 0 
10                 in
11                 y' := y
12                 end
13         end  
14 end     
15 p(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `let <decs> in <exp>`, `<decs>` needs to be one or more declarations.

In your case, on line 7 you do `y = 1` - note, this is not an assigment, but a comparison. That is, in C++ it would be equivalent to doing `y == 1`. You cannot assign to non-ref variables. (And in general, you want to avoid ref variables as much as possible.)
You could do `val y = 1` in its place, in which case you create a new value by the name of `y`, which shadows over the old `y` (but does not change it; you create a new value).

Likewise, on line 9, you do `x := 0`, which is not a declaration, but an expression, which assigns the value `0` to the reference value `x`, and then returns unit.

In addition, you can do multiple declarations in your let statements, so you don't need the nesting you do.

Finally, you write `p(x)` on the toplevel. You can only write expressions on the toplevel, if the declaration preceding ends with a semicolon; otherwise it believes it to be a part of the declaration. That is

```
val a = 5
6
```

is interpreted to be

```
val a = 5 6
```

In short, you could rewrite it to this:

```
val x = ref 0;

fun p(y': int ref)=
let
  val y = !y' (* this line might as well be deleted. *)
  val y = 1
in
  x := 0;
  y' := y
end;

p(x)
```

Or, the shorter version, since the SML has good type inference:

```
val x = ref 0;

fun p y' = (x := 0; y' := 1);

p x
```

I will say this, though; if you come from a language like C++ or similar, it may be tempting to use `'a ref`s a lot, but you will often find, that minimizing the use of them often leads to cleaner code in SML. (And other functional languages.)

Comment: thanks. this did not compile, but I got your idea and made a few changes and got it working. Question though, is Vi a good editor for SML? I feel like I've been getting errors because of newline and whitespace issues.

Comment: @FunBeans: I personally code SML in vim without any problems. Whitespace shouldn't be a problem, as it isn't significant in the language. In addition, [A Gentle Introduction to SML](http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/course-notes/sml/manual.html) may be nice to take a look at.

Answer (score 2):

`let y = 1 ...` is wrong. So is `let x := 0`. Inside `let ... in`, you need either `val` or `fun` declarations.

It seems you have some misunderstandings of SML. `let` is used to declare new local variables in a scope. It is strange for you to try to declare a variable named `y` in an inner scope that shadows the `y` that you declared in the `let` in the immediately outer scope. You either meant one of two things:

1. Change the value of the "y" variable defined in the outer scope. This is impossible. You cannot change the value of a variable in ML
2. You want to declared a new, unrelated variable that is also named "y", and hide the previous "y" within this scope; in this case, you would use `let var y = 1 in ...`

Also, it is strange that you have `let x := 0`. `x := 0` is a valid expression in itself. It changes the value contained in the reference pointed to by `x`. You don't need a `let`. Since `x := 0` is only evaluated for side effects, and returns type `unit` (i.e. nothing useful), you might familiarize yourself with the `;` operator, with which you can use to string together a bunch of side-effect "statements" which evaluate to the result of the last one: `x := 0; y' := y`